# Report is not getting added as part of build phase

Tags: gradle, jacoco

Added JACOCO HTML report in my Gradle build for java project. But Report was not getting added as part of build phase, need to execute gradle task jacocoTestReport to get report.

Pseudo Gradle build file :

```
apply plugin : 'java'
apply plugin : 'jacoco'

repositories { 
     jcenter()
     maven { maveno repo url }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
}

jacocoTestReport.mustRunAfter test
```

How to include Jacoco task in build phase of the project? So that no separate task needs to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `mustRunAfter` and `shouldRunAfter` only affect the execution **order** of tasks that will be executed anyway (e.g. when passed via command line).

To cause a task to be executed when another task is executed, use either `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`.

In your case, you could use `finalizedBy` on the `test` task:

```
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```